# Sympy randomly switches sign in symbols?

Tags: python, jupyter, sympy

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import *
w, t, a, x, y, k, z = sympy.symbols("w, t, a, x, y, k, z")
display(cos(w*t - a*x - k*z))
```

displays `cos(ax + kx - tw)` in jupyter notebook instead. What could I have possibly done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with equivalent expressions you can tell SymPy to not evaluate a given expression. Although the order of terms may change (as governed by the printing rules) the expression itself will not simplify. The way to do this is by using the `UnevaluatedExpr`:

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import *
>>> U = UnevaluatedExpr; D = Derivative
>>> f = cos(U(-x)); f
cos(-x)
>>> _.diff(x)
-sin(-x)*Derivative(-x, x)

# write special differentiator that will do the unevaluated Derivative

>>> dodiff = lambda f, x: f.diff(x).replace(lambda a: isinstance(a, D),
                                            lambda a: a.doit())
>>> dodiff(f, x)
sin(-x)
>>> _.doit()  # all will be evaluated
-sin(x)


>>> cos(U(-x)).subs(x, pi)
cos(-pi)
>>> _.doit()
-1
```

Functions like `solve` will not work -- but should (maybe?) -- with such expressions because they don't currently introspect and extract the desired symbol,

```py
>>> solve(U(w*t - a*x - k*z), x)
[]
>>> solve(U(w*t - k*z) - a*x, x)
[(-k*z + t*w)/a]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sympy orders variables alphabetically (based on `ord`). So, it has rearranged what you put in to achieve that. What you wrote and what sympy produced are mathematically equivalent since `cos` is an even function, i.e. `cos(x) = cos(-x)`. If you had instead done `sin`, sympy would have returned `-sin(ax + kx - tw)`; notice the sign change because `sin` is an odd function, i.e. `sin(-x) = -sin(x)`.

Comment: Is there a way to stop this behavior? It throws me off, having it mess around with my equations that way. Additionally, taking derivative wrt x does produce a different result

Comment: @MrSomeone I'm not aware of any way to turn that off. I'd just recommend getting familiar with what is equivalent to what. And after you print out the first term, taking derivatives and whatnot should maintain a similar order, so from there on it shouldn't be too confusing.

Comment: When you say "stop this behaviour" it is difficult to know how far you want to take it. Do you want to prevent things like `cos(0) -> 1`? You can use `evaluate(false)` as in the other answer but typically that prevents simplifications that most people would expect.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to achieve your result is:

```py
import sympy
w, t, a, x, y, k, z = sympy.symbols("w, t, a, x, y, k, z")
argument = w*t - a*x - k*z
with sympy.evaluate(False):
    expr = sympy.cos(argument)
# some manipulation
expr = expr * 2
print(expr)
# out 2*cos(-a*x - k*z + t*w)

# some other manipulations
print(solve(expr, w))
# out: [(a*x + k*z + pi/2)/t, (a*x + k*z + 3*pi/2)/t]
```

Note that I wrote `argument` outside of the `evaluate` context manager. If you move it inside, you will see that `argument` too would not be evaluated, resulting in a nested expression tree.

Also note, this worked in this simple example, but it might not work in more complex ones.

Comment: You can also use `sympy.cos(expr, evaluate=False)`. Note though that many operations like `subs` will trigger evaluation later even if you prevent it at the start so it is difficult to do much manipulation with "unevaluated" expressions.